# MVC3 JQuery validation not working in non-English locales

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, forms, validation

In my application, we have a page where we are able to edit a user's details. Some of this information is validated to ensure that some fields are required while others are not. When an invalid entry is input, we see the following validation messages:

http://gyazo.com/693fefaa64693ebbddbe1484f9b20cb8

This is fine when working in an English locale, however the website also runs in Swedish and the form is displayed as followed:

http://gyazo.com/7a426e503dc7243b68cba0b41fe7509d

So far so good, but when we submit the form with empty fields, the validation is bypassed and the entry is sent off with the following message:

http://gyazo.com/4bd7922485e0df603212583aea8bdf8c

I believe along the lines of "Data updated." For the life of me I can't pin down the cause of this issue. Please see below for the validation of the form in the scripting of the page:

```
    $("#edit_owner_form").validate({
        onfocusout: function(element)
        {
            //do nothing on focus out
        },
        onkeyup:function()
        {
           //do nothing on keyup
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
        return true;
        },
        rules: {
            Website: { url: true },
            TransactionRetentionPeriodInDays: { number: true },
            Company: { required: true },
            City: { required: true },
            Country: { required: true },
            PhoneNumber: { required: true }
        },
        messages: {
            Company: { required: COMPANY_NAME_REQUIRED },
            City: { required: TOWN_CITY_REQUIRED },
            Country: { required: COUNTRY_REQUIRED },
            PhoneNumber: { required: PHONENUMBER_REQUIRED },
            Website: { url: WEBSITE_REQUIRED }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.appendTo($('#errorbox'));
            $("#errorbox label").css("color","#B94A48;");
            $("#ownerdetail").show();
            },

    });
```

All of the messages are pre-defined variables which are picking up the correct culture but at no point being displayed. I will also provide the form itself for reference:

```
<form id="edit_owner_form">
<div class="container" id="ownerDetails">
    <input type="hidden" name="OwnerId" id="OwnerId" value="@Model.OwnerId" />
    <table>
        <tr style="vertical-align: top;">
            <td style="width: 300px; vertical-align: top;">
                <div id="left" style="vertical-align: top; clear: both; height: 470px;">
                    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold;">
                        @Language.CompanyName&nbsp;<span class="reqd-field">*</span>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input type="text" name="Company" id="Company" value="@Model.Company" style="width:260px;" />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold;">
                        @Language.Street</div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input type="text" name="Street" id="Street" value="@Model.Street" style="width:260px;" />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold;">
                        @Language.PostalZip</div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input type="text" name="PostalZIP" id="PostalZIP" value="@Model.PostalZIP" style="width:260px;" />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold;">
                        @Language.PhoneNumber&nbsp;<span class="reqd-field">*</span></div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input type="text" name="PhoneNumber" id="PhoneNumber" value="@Model.PhoneNumber" style="width:260px;" />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold;">
                        @Language.Website</div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input type="text" name="Website" id="Website" value="@Model.Website" style="width:260px;" />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold;">
                        @Language.GLN</div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input type="text" name="GLN" id="GLN" style="width: 260px;" value="@Model.GLN" /></div>
                    <br />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 300px; vertical-align: top;">
                <div id="right" style="vertical-align: top; clear: both; height: 470px;">
                    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold;">
                        @Language.Number</div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input type="text" name="Number" id="Number" value="@Model.Number" style="width:260px;" /></div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold;">
                        @Language.TownCity&nbsp;<span class="reqd-field">*</span></div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input type="text" name="City" id="City" value="@Model.City" style="width:260px;" />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold;">
                        @Language.Country&nbsp;<span class="reqd-field">*</span></div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country, Model.AvailableCountries != null ? Model.AvailableCountries : new SelectList(new[] { "" }), new { id = "Country", name = "Country", style = "width:260px;height:30px !important;" })
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold;">
                        @Language.FaxNumber</div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input type="text" name="FaxNumber" id="FaxNumber" value="@Model.FaxNumber" style="width:260px;" />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold;">
                        @Language.Currency</div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CurrencyCode_CurrencyCodeId, Model.CurrencyCodes != null ? Model.CurrencyCodes : new SelectList(new[] { "" }), new { id = "CurrencyCode_Code", style = "width:260px;height:30px !important;" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
```

Is there something I am missing when working with validation in different cultures? I appreciate any and all responses, I am truly stumped! Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using the Validation HtmlHelpers?

Comment: I do not believe we are in this part of the site for some reason. All the code is exactly as I have posted. After a bit of debugging, I can see that when we are in Swedish, '$("#edit_owner_form").validate' is not getting hit at all. Any suggestion as to why this could be halted due to the culture?

Comment: In fact it appears none of the JavaScript within '$(document).ready' is getting hit while in Swedish, how strange.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in the end it was fairly simple, it was just down to the way that Swedish characters are rendered in the code. Some special characters must have been interfering with the JavaScript and stopping it from running. Just a matter of tracking down the troublesome extract. Cheers!

Comment: Lo and behold, the issue was caused by a simple return carriage in a localised string which was used to throw a JavaScript error. Some things really can just sneak by.